# My USA Student visa has cancelled. Now I'm applying UK student visa, is there any problem previous USA visa cancel

Tags: uk, canada, visa-refusals

i have Canada student visa refusal, Australia student visa refusal.
USA student visa Cancelled at immigration. is there any problem creates for UK student visa if i apply? please help me out. 
my profile
SSC 88%
Intermediate- 97%
BTech 80% civil engineering 2017 passout
2017 to till date work experience related to civil industry.

can i apply UK student visa and is there any problem creates my previous student visa refusals ??

Comment: What were the reason(s) for the US visa cancellation and the two refusals? In themselves they don’t automatically preclude you from applying to the UK assuming you meet the eligibility criteria, but you’ll have to disclose your immigration history. You should be aware that these 4 countries (plus New Zealand) share Immigration data.

Comment: They also share many of their concerns about visas, so consistent refusals and cancellations may mean there is something about your application that the UK will also consider a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The UK asks about previous refusals. Obviously you should tell the truth. The US, Canada, and the UK exchange *quite* a lot of data and if they find that you lied your application will be automatically refused. When you tell truthfully that you have been refused, there will be **extra scrutiny** of your application.

## So yes, it is a problem.

You will have to be careful to explain that you are a genuine student, that you have good reasons to return to your home country after studying, and that you will not work illegally in the UK.

Since you have received several visa refusals, consider what impression you are giving in your applications.

- What are your academic credentials so far, and does it appear logical for you to study abroad?
- How are you funding your studies?